# How to get global selector inside emulated view encapsulation (CSS / Angular2)

Tags: css, angular, ng2-bootstrap, angular2viewencapsulation

I have a Home component with this inside:

```
<alert type="info">Hello from ng2-bootstrap</alert>
```

Inside my home.style.scss, I have this:

```
:host .alert {
  background-color: green;
}
```

which should change the background color to green, but it does not.

The above css code will produce this style:

```
[_nghost-wjn-3]   .alert[_ngcontent-wjn-3] {
  background-color: green;
}
```

and the final HTML looks like this:

```
<home _nghost-wjn-3="">
  <div _ngcontent-wjn-3="" class="card-container">
    <alert _ngcontent-wjn-3="" type="info" ng-reflect-type="info">
      <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" ng-reflect-initial-classes="alert" ng-reflect-ng-class="alert-info">
        Hello from ng2-bootstrap  Sat Sep 17 2016
      </div>
    </alert>
  </div>
</home>
```

I don't know what the problem is here, but I think the selector is wrong. I'd like the final selector to be:

```
[_nghost-wjn-3]   .alert
```

instead of:

```
[_nghost-wjn-3]   .alert[_ngcontent-wjn-3]
```

Or in other words, why is there no _ngcontent-wjn-3 attribute on `<div class="alert">...</div>`?

Maybe I'm doing the whole thing wrong. What I'm trying to achieve is to customize the CSS of the individual bootstrap components (`<alert>` in the code above) as provided by the ng2-bootrap library (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap) inside my custom components (`<home>` in the code above).

I'm using the default view encapsulation (emulated) in the home component.

How can I do that please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out myself. This is what I was looking for:

```
:host /deep/ .alert {
  background-color: green;
}
```

The above code will produce the following:

```
[_nghost-wjn-3] .alert {
  background-color: green;
}
```

This way I can modify the default styles of a bootstrap class (.alert, in this case) inside of my component `<home>`.

Source: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html

Answer (score 0):

You need:

`[_nghost-wjn-3] alert[_ngcontent-wjn-3]`

Instead of:

`[_nghost-wjn-3] .alert[_ngcontent-wjn-3]`

If you go and check your structure, **alert tag** has the `ngcontent...` attribute, **not** his div child with **alert class**.

Comment: That's right but I need to set the background-color of the `<div class="alert">...</div>` element, not the `<alert>` element. How do you set up your selector then? I tried this: `:host alert .alert { background-color: green; }`, which creates: `[_nghost-wjn-3]   alert[_ngcontent-wjn-3] .alert[_ngcontent-wjn-3] { background-color: green; }` but this style won't apply because `<div class="alert">...</div>` has no `_ngcontent-wjn-3`. Is there a way to tell the css to not append the `[_ngcontent-wjn-3]` to the .alert?